# Excel formula works independantly but not when i put it in list data validation

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I am using a nested FILTER formula to create a very specific list of values and then feed that into 'list' data validation.

Filter level 1: I have a long list of 'rooms' in 2 locations and I filter them based on which location is selected in cell H9
*List of rooms is in N3:N220; location is in M3:M220*

Filter level 2: I exclude all rooms which have been booked on overlapping dates based on comparing check-in and check-out date input by user (E9, F9) with check-in and check-out dates of previous reservations in rows above (E2:E8, F2:F8). if any of above rows overlap in terms of date, I exclude corresponding room (I2:I8).

The formula works fine when I put it in cell I9 and returns an array of 'rooms in location H9, available on dates E9 to F9'. However, when I provide it as an input in 'list' data validation for cell I9, it says "The source currently evaluates to an error".

Thank you!

Formula in question:

=FILTER(FILTER($N$3:$N$220,($M$3:$M$220=H9)),ISNA(MATCH(FILTER($N$3:$N$220,($M$3:$M$220=H9)),UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER($I$2:$I8,($H$2:$H8=$H9)*NOT(($E$2:$E8>$F9)+($F$2:$F8<=$E9))),"")),0)))

The formula works fine when I put it in cell I9 and returns an array of 'rooms in location H9, available on dates E9 to F9'. However, when I provide it as an input in 'list' data validation for cell I9, it says "The source currently evaluates to an error".

I expected that after putting in data validation, I get a drop-down list from which I can select one of the available rooms.

Comment: The formula needs to be indexed you cannot enter directly an array in data validation, place the formula in some other blank cells and use the formula then in data validation, say for example you have placed it in cell `ZZ1` reference in validation as `=ZZ1#`